# Wordpress plugin: Getting posts where checkbox selected

Tags: plugins, posts, get-posts

I would like to have a plugin where I could work with all post data from posts that have a selected checkbox..

To get all posts is simple with the `get_posts( $args );` function...

But how to add a checkbox to every post? So that I can use the filter parameter of the `get_posts( $args );` function to get only the selected ones?

Hope you understand what I mean ;)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is the functionality you ask for any different than basic implementation of post tags? http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Tags_Screen

Answer (score 1):

Just use Post tags.

> Every post in WordPress can be filed under one or more Tags. This aids in navigation and allows posts and to be grouped with others of similar content. ([from Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Tags_Screen))

You can query posts in various ways. Most solid is of course the `wp_query` class. Use it like this:

```
// The Query
$args = array('tag' => YOUR_DESIRED_TAG_SLUG);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

More on querying by tag: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Also, if you don't want to waste post tags for that, you can [create custom non-hierarchic taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies), which is, again, built-in Wordpress sollution.

Comment: Thanks for u quick reply!
Good idea to use the post tags, I will try this!

Comment: Please do. And if you'll go this route, please mark this question as answered.